# NLP - Deep belief neural networks or logic?

Tags: natural-language-processing

The NLP progresses seems to me that has split in two big group of thoughts:

1. Deep learning have a neural network with multiple layers that has been trained and learned to represent knowledge and understand the meaning of sentences. However, such system would be difficult to debug and correct
2. Logic and inference, label parts of speech and learn by inference and using tools such as Natural logic.

Can someone point out if anything is wrong in these conclusions? Is there any other stream of thoughts that I should be taking into consideration?

Comment: Which conclusions? Note that your last question effectively asks for a summary of the field, which is too broad for SE.

Comment: I am sorry if it sounds very broad. I am asking for correctedness for my statements and if I am missing something on the field

Comment: Note that many machine learning techniques are employed in NLP, not just Neural Networks. For example, SVMs are very effective at Word Sense Disambiguation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very briefly:

Option 1 faces difficulties since [certain connectionist models are incapable of learning natural languages](http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/harnad/Papers/Py104/pinker.conn.html).

Option 2 faces grave difficulties due to many negative results, notably [Gold's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105187/converse-of-golds-theorem-and-necessary-condition-for-unlearnability).
There's a nice [overview](http://grammars.grlmc.com/papers/paper_def.pdf) which includes a discussion of probabilistic approaches.

Generally, the response to these difficulties has been to look at [other sources of information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28linguistics%29) beyond the linguistic input alone.